# JWT deoded in Typescript gives the error "Object is possibly 'undefined"

Tags: typescript, jwt, decoder

I am trying to decode the JWT token in order to check wheather is it valid or not.
But I am getting the error that the decoded object is possibly 'undefined'

```
import jwt_decode, { JwtPayload } from "jwt-decode";
    if (token) {
      const decoded = jwt_decode<JwtPayload>(token || "") || null;

      if (decoded) {
        const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
        if (decoded?.exp < currentTime) {  //Object is possibly 'undefined'.
          dispatch(logout());
          localStorage.removeItem("token");
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the `JwtPayload` type definition ? I have reasons to believe it comes from here

Comment: @nook I have updated the question, jwtpayload comes from the library jwt-decode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`decoded.exp` is possibly `undefined`, so you have to check it first before comparing it to `currentTime`

```
if (decoded?.exp && decoded.exp < currentTime) { }
```

Comment: the `?` in  `decoded?.exp < currentTime` already does that. It can end up comparing `undefined < currentTime` instead but that's not a problem either because that's always `false`

Comment: @zapl exp is possibly undefined too, it does seem to fix the compilation error try it out here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgU1IuAuGBXMiBmBLMBOGAHxgG8YEAPAB3TAwFsAjBAJ1M2wX0OIC+MALwUqddFlwEiMAQG4AUIrw4YACkTIiASgqKYMUJFjAM7dgjBQAKniYIRMACIBDKAgB0YEAHd1egD0MACMAAwRSoaqGlogKJ40tDAAZCnwSPFEAPyJdDAAPEbmltZ2DnqUMAZyigJAA

Comment: oops, right, `strictNullChecks` doesn't like undefined < number